# What other ways can I draw the outline of an object?

Tags: opengl

I have a very simple case. I want to draw the outline of an object, in this case I think they'll only be spheres, but I'd like to not rely on this.

I've found methods such as:

1. Draw the object to the stencil buffer
2. Turn on wireframe mode
3. Draw the object with thick lines
4. Draw the real object on the top

The problem I have with this method is that my models have a lot of vertices, and this requires me to draw it three times. I'm getting some significant frame rate drops.

Are there other ways to do this? My next guess would be to draw circles on the final render as a post-process effect, seeing as I'm only looking at spheres. But I'd much much rather do this for more than just spheres.

Is there something I can do in an existing shader to outline?

I'd also like the outline to appear when the object is behind others.

I'm using OpenGL 4.3.

Comment: Could you show how did you implement it with spencil buffer? I don't think it should cause noticable frame rate loss.

Comment: @eldo There's no LOD going on, but wireframe mode slows things down considerably if the camera is close enough to see the individual triangles. At a distance, where they sort of meld into one red blob (rendering them as red), the frame rate is normal.

Answer (score 9):

I know 3 ways of doing contour rendering:

#### Using the stencil buffer

The first one is a slightly modified version of the one you described: you first render your object as normal with stencil buffer on, then you slightly scale it and render it plain color where the stencil buffer is not filled. You can find an explanation of this technique [here](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing).

#### Using image processing techniques

The second one is a post-process step, where you look for edges using image processing filters (like [the sobel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator)) and you compose your rendering with your contour detection result. The good thing with the sobel operator is that it is separable; this means you can do the detection in two 1D passes, which is more efficient that doing one 2D pass.

#### Using the geometry shader

Last but not least, you can use the geometry shader to extract the silhouette of your mesh. The idea is to use adjacent vertices of a triangle to detect if one edge of this triangle (let call it `t0`) is a *contour*.

To do this, for each edge `ei` of `t0`:

- build a new triangle `ti` using the vertices of `ei` and its associated vertex,
- compute the normal `ni` of `ti`, and the normal `n0` of `t0`, transform them both in view space (the silhouette depends on the point of view),
- compute the dot product between `n0` and `ni`. If its value is negative, this means that the normals are in opposite directions and the edge `ei` is a silhouette edge.
- You then build a quad around `ei`, `emit` each of its vertices and color them the way you want in the fragment shader.

This is the basic idea of this algorithm. Using only this will result in aliased edges, with holes between them, but this can be improved. You can read [this paper](http://cg.iit.bme.hu/~szecsi/cikkek/crease12/crease_hajagos_final.pdf), and [this blog post](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=54) for further informations.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you get good results if you render the outlined object in white (unlit) to a texture as big as the final framebuffer, then draw a framebuffer-sized quad with that texture and have the fragment shader blur or otherwise process it and apply the desired color.

I have an example [here](http://geoffprewett.com/blog/software/opengl-outline/)